# cant set for loop that count down in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have noticed that when using for loop in objective c, i cant set the loop to go down like:

```
for(int i=16; i<=1; i-- )
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",i);
    }
```

He would not print `i` .
How can i do that anyway ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your for statement is incorrect, you check (second part of the for) `i<=1`. This defines while `i` is smaller or equal to 1 and this should be `i>=1`: while `i` is larger or equal to 1.

```
for(int i=16; i>=1; i-- )
{
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed up the `<=` with `>=`

```
for(int i = 16; i >= 1; i-- )
{
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=16; i>=1; i-- )
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to the following one :

```
for(int i=16; i>=1; i-- )
{
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
}
```